# Complex Number Maths

Tags: complex-numbers

I have started Complex Number question. I have tried solving but I cant find the answer.Kindly Assist.
Given that $z=\cos θ +i\sin θ$

Prove $z+\frac{1}{z}=2\cos θ$

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}$. Multiply top and bottom by $\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$.

Comment: i have done that after doing it  get cos^2 θ + sin^2 θ. im stuck from here.

Comment: When you do the multiplications I suggested, you should get $\frac{\cos\theta-i\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}$. But the new bottom is just $1$, and it's almost over.

Comment: If you're studying complex numbers, naveenath, but you don't know $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$, then I strongly recommend you sit down with a book that does trigonometric functions and study it closely. You will need it. A lot.

Answer (score 2):

If $$z = \cos θ + i\sin θ$$

then$$ z+1/z =\cos θ + i\sin θ+\frac{1}{\cos θ + i\sin θ} =$$

$$\cos θ+i\sin θ+\frac{1}{\cos θ+i\sin θ}\cdot\frac{\cos θ - i\sin θ}{\cos θ - i\sin θ} =$$
$$\cos θ+i\sin θ+\frac{\cos θ -i\sin θ}{\cos^2 θ + \sin^2 θ} =$$
$$\cos θ+i\sin θ+\frac{\cos θ -i\sin θ}{1} =2\cos θ$$

Comment: Just some algebra-which of course is what makes complex numbers so cool.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $z = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ we have
$$|z|^2 = z \bar{z} = (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) (\cos \theta - i \sin \theta) = \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$$ and hence
$$\frac{1}{z} = \bar{z} = \cos \theta - i \sin \theta.$$

Substituting gives
$$z + \frac{1}{z} = (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) + (\cos \theta - i \sin \theta) = 2 \cos \theta.$$

Alternatively, once we know that $\frac{1}{z} = \bar{z}$ for the $z$ in question, we have
$$z + \frac{1}{z} = z + \bar{z} = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}(z + \bar{z}) = 2 \Re z = 2 \cos \theta.$$

Answer (score 0):

Polar form: $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=e^{i\theta}$ hence $1/z=z^{-1}=e^{-i\theta}=\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta)=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$ from which
$$
z+\frac1z=e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta+\cos\theta-i\sin\theta=2\cos\theta
$$
as requested.